# Extract string within delimiters

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql

I have a string `{1:F01BPHKPLPKXXX0000000000}` from which I need to extract `1:F01BPHKPLPKXXX0000000000` using `regex_substr`. Can you please help me with this ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow! Have you tried anything yet? Please show us the code.

Answer (score 1):

Why use REGEXP_SUBSTR? Using pistol to kill a mouse?

You just need to `TRIM` those braces.

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT q'[{1:F01BPHKPLPKXXX0000000000}]' STR FROM DUAL)
  3  select rtrim(ltrim(str,'{'),'}') str from data
  4  /

STR
--------------------------
1:F01BPHKPLPKXXX0000000000

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
select regexp_replace('{1:F01BPHKPLPKXXX0000000000}', '{(.*)}', '\1')
from   dual
```

It takes everything between the brackets and outputs that.

This can be much easier if you ask me, using `substr`:

```
select substr(var, 2, length(var)-2)
from   (select '{1:F01BPHKPLPKXXX0000000000}' var from dual)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('{1:F01BPHKPLPKXXX0000000000}', '[^{].*[^}]') FROM DUAL
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use regexp_replace.  I just use the alternation operator, `|`, so that I ask to replace `{` at the beginning (using the anchor `^`) and `}` at the end of the string (using the anchor `$`).

```
SCOTT@dev> WITH a_tab AS
  2    (SELECT '{1:F01BPHKPLPKXXX0000000000}' a_col FROM dual
  3    )
  4  SELECT regexp_replace (a_col, '^{|}$') FROM a_tab
  5  /

REGEXP_REPLACE(A_COL,'^{|}$')
==========================
1:F01BPHKPLPKXXX0000000000
```